# Remove all JSON objects from JSON array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have this so far, and it removes only one object, and there are 4 that should be removed.

```
SET @JSON = '[{"one": 5},{"two":2},{"one": 5},{"three":3},{"one": 5},{"one": 5}]';
SET @TO_REMOVE = '{"one": 5}';

SET @JSON = REPLACE(@JSON, @TO_REMOVE, '"DELETED"');
SET @JSON = JSON_REMOVE(@JSON, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(@JSON, 'one', 'DELETED')));

SELECT @JSON;

#returns the following:
[{"two": 2}, "DELETED", {"three": 3}, "DELETED", "DELETED"]
```

What I really want is a method like the above, but instead of putting in 'one' in JSON_SEARCH I want to put 'all'. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(@JSON, 'one', 'DELETED')) AS `Single`; #returns: $[0]
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(@JSON, 'all', 'DELETED')) AS `Multi`;  #returns: ["$[0]", "$[2]", "$[4]", "$[5]"]
```

Is there a way to pass in each value `["$[0]", "$[2]", "$[4]", "$[5]"]` into JSON_REMOVE, like you have `...` in JavaScript for function arguements.

Thanks, please let me know alternative methods as well.

Comment: Unless you upgrade to MySQL 8, you're probably stuck with trying to use a technique as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows) to split the result for `JSON_SEARCH(...'all'...)` into separate path elements to pass to `JSON_REMOVE`

Comment: Still looking for more answers.

Comment: are you using a stored procedure? You could do this with a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "brutal" way: Just REPLACE them:

```
SET @JSON = '[{"one": 5},{"two":2},{"one": 5},{"three":3},{"one": 5},{"one": 5}]';
SET @TO_REMOVE = '{"one": 5}';

SET @JSON = REPLACE(@JSON, CONCAT(@TO_REMOVE, ','), '');
SET @JSON = REPLACE(@JSON, CONCAT(',', @TO_REMOVE), '');
SET @JSON = REPLACE(@JSON, @TO_REMOVE, '');

SELECT @JSON;
```

Result:

```
| @JSON                   |
| ----------------------- |
| [{"two":2},{"three":3}] |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dzCtBv7bCxPKnghfLPggZJ/0)

Note that we have to handle three cases:

- A matching item followed by another item (has `,` behind it)
- A matching item which ist the last item (not followed by any item but has a `,` in front of it)
- A matching item which is the only item in the array (not surrounden by `,`)

In MySQL 8: Unpack the array with [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), then filter and pack the elements again with [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg):

```
SET @JSON = '[{"one": 5},{"two":2},{"one": 5},{"three":3},{"one": 5},{"one": 5}]';
SET @TO_REMOVE = '{"one": 5}';

SET @JSON = (
  SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(item)
  FROM JSON_TABLE(
    @JSON,
    '$[*]' columns (item JSON path '$')
  ) t
  WHERE item <> CAST(@TO_REMOVE AS JSON)
);

SELECT @JSON;
```

Result:

```
| @JSON                      |
| -------------------------- |
| [{"two": 2}, {"three": 3}] |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pmgqNGSatSdv3wnaCoH7N6/0)

Note that the order of the elements can change, because we cannot control the order for `JSON_ARRAYAGG`.